# Highcharts make pie chart show 0 data

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

When I have the following data supplied to Pie chart: `[[0],[0],[0]]`, the chart is empty.

However, I want to make the pie show three slices, with each percentage distribution equal to `33.3%`

I know it is better to use bar / column chart in this case, however I have this edge case where I need to show 0 data in Pie chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround**:

Set some nonzero value and add `isZero` flag for every point. Then use this flag in `tooltip.pointFormatter`:

```
tooltip: {
  pointFormatter: function() {
    return "<span style='color:" + this.color + "'>\u25CF</span>" + this.series.name + ": <b>" + (this.options.isZero ? 0 : this.y) + "</b><br/>";
  } 
}
```

This will cause that your points will be visible and `0` will be printed in tooltip if the hovered point has `isZero` flag set to `true`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/52a1xh99/